Show that $x<0$ is not part of the domain of a relation.
I have sketched the graph of $A=x^2+2x\sqrt{y^2+\frac{x^2}{4}}$ for a fixed positive constant $A$ and noticed that the domain is $x\geq 0$. Taking this as an inspiration, I tried to show that $$A=x^2+2x\sqrt{y^2+\frac{x^2}{4}} \implies x\geq 0$$ but I did not succeed. The following is my attempt:
Suppose $x<0$ for the proof of contradiction. Then,
$$x<0 \implies \frac{x^2}{4}>0 \implies h^2+\frac{x^2}{4}>0 \implies \sqrt{h^2+\frac{x^2}{4}}>0$$
$$\implies 2x\sqrt{h^2+\frac{x^2}{4}}<0 \implies A<x^2 \implies 0<x^2 \implies x<0$$
and then I'm stuck. Would appreciate any help and thank you for your time.

When $x<0$,
$$A=x^2+x\sqrt{x^2+4y^2}\leq x^2+x\sqrt{x^2}=x^2-x^2=0,$$
which contradicts $A>0$.

Thank you for your time!

Consider the second term in your expression. $2x\sqrt{y^2+\frac{x^2}{4}} = x\sqrt{4y^2+x^2}.$ If A is positive, that implies
$$x^2>-x\sqrt{4y^2+x^2}.$$
However, for $x = -k$ for some $k$, the LHS is $k^2$ and the RHS = $k\sqrt{4y^2+k^2}>k^2.$ This implies that $x$ cannot be negative if $A$ is positive.

Thank you for your time! Your answer is also very good!
